# bxslider + Chrome background position fixed

Tags: google-chrome, bxslider, background-position

Using bxslider, I've set my slides to 100% height/width and used background images. Applying background-attachement:fixed transitions, but the images are mostly missing if not completely in Chrome.

background-attachement:fixed transitions properly vertically and horizontally in IE and vertically in Firefox, with the images displaying properly.

here is a pen...

```
[http://codepen.io/RyanThompson/pen/raajXL]
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks